# How to handle IDP metadata change dynamically without tomcat restart

Tags: spring-saml

I am using Spring SAML SSO extension for integrating with ADFS.

Currently, I have configured IDP metadata as `org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource`. We are noticing changes in IDP metadata(Certificates) which is causing authentication failures.

How can I fetch IDP metadata dynamically without restarting tomcat? Would `org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.HTTPMetadataProvider` help in this scenario?